# Labeling enclosed line in center using QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, line

I would like to dynamically label a hiking circuit in the center (if the line is acting like a polygon and the label is centered). You can see it in the screenshot below:

[image]

I know I could do the following:

1. Line to Polygon
2. Label in the center of the polygon

But I need a fast and dynamic solution to save Hardware Resources. It's not for printing a hiking map, is for working in different scales within QGIS. I tried several label settings but found no solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the ["Geometry Generator"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) of the label placement tab, use the following expression:

```sql
centroid(make_polygon($geometry))  -- use point_on_surface or pole_of_inaccessibility in place of centroid to guarantee the label is inside the shape
```

A polygon is made from the line [`$geometry`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#geometry) and its centroid is used as the label position.

[image]

Comment: Why not simply `centroid ($geometry)`? Works also for a polyline - even if it is not closed.

Comment: `make_polygon` works on an unclosed line. In the case of a horseshoe shape the centroid might not be 'inside' the line. In which case `point_on_surface` or `pole_of_inaccessibility` would be preferable.